# Does Rails Offer an API for Rendering A Translated Model Name with Count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model, count, rails-i18n

I have my model names declared in `config/locales/models.en.yml`:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    models:
        news_item:
            zero: No News Items
            one: News Item
            other: News Items
```

I know I can get the correctly pluralized model name using:

```
NewsItem.model_name.human(count: n)
```

So I could do:

```
"#{n} {NewsItem.model_name.human(count: n)}
```

Which is fine for 1 and many items, but with no items will render:

```
0 No News Items
```

Obviously I can add some logic to skip rendering the numeric part if there are no items, but I'm wondering if Rails has this built in?

There is a basic translation method that does what I'm after, but it doesn't pick up on model name translations:

```
I18n.translate :news_item, count: 2
```

Gives the error:

> "translation missing: en.news_item"

Comment: Is this helpful ? http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-pluralize

Comment: @ArupRakshit Nope. Because that takes no notice of the model name(s) in the locale file.

Comment: instead of `0 No News Items` you want `No News Items` ?

Comment: I said you to use something like `NewsItem.model_name.human(count: n).pluralize`

Comment: @ArupRakshit That makes no sense. You are asking the model to give you the correct (pluralized or not) translated name for the given count and then pluralizing it. I want the equivalent of `I18n.translate :news_items, count: n` but using the model's `human_name` which is drawn from the locale file.

Comment: As you got the error, `I18n.translate :news_items, count: 2` will work if you rename the model name in the translation file to `news_items`.

Comment: The extra `s` was a typo, but the error is the same either way.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the answer is no, so I've created a helper method that does this:

```
  def humanize_with_prefixed_count(clazz, count)
    [count, clazz.model_name.human(count: count)].delete_if{ |x| x == 0}.join(' ')
  end
```

Use:

```
humanize_with_prefixed_count(NewsItem, 0) # No NewsItems
humanize_with_prefixed_count(NewsItem, 1) # 1 NewsItem
humanize_with_prefixed_count(NewsItem, 2) # 2 NewsItems

clazz.model_name.human # News Item
```